How to add a controller to a model(SDF) which contains drake:mimic tag in Drake?
The problem I have met is that when I used the tag “drake:mimic” in SDF，everything goes ok at the beginning.
But when I want to add a lower controller  in my simulation,I was told that I have to use a discrete system,or the drake:mimic joint would be ignored.
I did set it as a discrete system,but the controller base on PIDcontroller is a continues system so that the problem exists.
Does anyone who met this problem before?

Is the message you are seeing something along the line of "Mimic elements are currently only supported by MultibodyPlant with a discrete time step and using DiscreteContactSolver::kSap"? If so and you are already using a discrete MultibodyPlant, then you need to switch to using SAP. You can do that through MultibodyPlant::set_discrete_contact_approximation()  or MultibodyPlantConfig::discrete_contact_approximation

Sorry for that I don't describe it clearly at the begining.
I did use "DiscreteContactSolver::kSap" and I also make sure  I use it sucessfully.

I think the problem is  discrete time step.It seems be same as the problem that described by RussTedrake in this website."https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/18917"

I fell down in adding a Inverse Dynamics Controller.

To be clear, you can use a continuous-time controller (e.g. PidController) with a discrete-time MultibodyPlant.  That is perfectly fine.
If you have a mimic joint in your system, you will want to use the state_projection and output_projection matrices so that you are controlling only the directly actuated joints.  (The simulator will then make the mimic-ed joints track).
Here is an example of how you might create that state projection matrix:
def MakePidStateProjectionMatrix(plant: MultibodyPlant):
    """Given a MultibodyPlant, returns a selection matrix, S, such that [q_a; v_a] = S @ [q; v], where q_a and v_a are the actuated positions and velocities and q, v, are the full state. This can be passed to e.g. the `state_projection` argument of the PidController constructor.

    Args:
        plant: The MultibodyPlant for the projection matrix.
    """
    num_q = plant.num_positions()
    num_v = plant.num_velocities()
    num_u = plant.num_actuators()
    S = np.zeros((2 * num_u, num_q + num_v))
    j = 0
    for i in range(plant.num_actuators()):
        actuator = plant.get_joint_actuator(JointActuatorIndex(i))
        assert actuator.num_inputs() == 1
        joint = actuator.joint()
        S[j, joint.position_start()] = 1
        S[num_u + j, num_q + joint.velocity_start()] = 1
        j = j + 1
    return S

